# How to manually present DatePicker in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, datepicker

I want to show a DatePicker in SwiftUI. But the SwiftUI have no interface to customization the style of DatePicker, etc, font size ,font color . So I want to use a button to show DatePicker. After click this button , the SwiftUI DatePicker will be present.

Is there any way to implement this?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var date = Date()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack() {
                DatePicker(selection: $date, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                    Text("")
                }
                .opacity(0.01)
                HStack() {
                    Text("Start Time")
                    Spacer()
                    Button("2021-08-22") {
                        print("Button was tapped")
                        // present DatePicker...
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 44)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution as bellow:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var date = Date()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack() {
                HStack() {
                    Text("Start Time")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("2021-08-22")
                }
                DatePicker(selection: $date, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                    Text("")
                }
                .opacity(0.011)
            }
            .frame(height: 44)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to do what you want - it does nothing?